# Che significa 'diserbato' in «uno spazio diserbato di dolore e rimpianto»?

Tags: grammar

Su un quotidiano online c'è scritto:

> Muore un grande regista e lascia uno *spazio diserbato* di dolore e rimpianto, uno strappo senza rimedio, per chi gli è stato accanto negli ultimi giorni, nelle ultime ore, amici stretti e devoti come Tornatore, Giordana, Andò, Scola.

C'è qualcuno che è in grado di capire cosa significhi *diserbato* nel frammento 'uno spazio diserbato di dolore e rimpianto'?

Answer (score 6):

*Diserbare* significa eliminare le erbacce (da un terreno), i *diserbanti* sono infatti prodotti che svolgono questa funzione.

Nel caso della frase in questione si tratta evidentemente di un uso figurato del participio del verbo. 
Interpreterei lo "spazio diserbato" come uno spazio brullo, privato di ogni componente fertile: lo *spazio diserbato di dolore e rimpianto* è quindi un metaforico terreno privo di qualunque cosa eccetto il dolore e il rimpianto. Chi scrive sta descrivendo un'emozione, quella della tristezza che accompagna la morte di una persona cara.

Personalmente non mi piace molto questo uso del verbo, in quanto *diserbare* ha il significato (anche letterale) di estirpare qualcosa di cattivo (le erbacce che impediscono la coltivazione, un terreno diserbato è dunque un terreno fertile); nella frase in questione si dà invece a *diserbato* un'accezione negativa, come a dire che lo spazio diserbato è qui uno spazio sterile, triste, solo. 
Forse l'autore mirava a raggiungere un senso di paradosso.